# How to remove waypoints from bing map in c#

Tags: c#, bing-maps

I am not able to remove waypoints from bing map in c# (WPF), i had used waypoint remove, clear, removeat but still not removed.....

1. How to remove waypoints from bing map in c#
2. also provide code to delete the path between waypoints

Source and destination are Location(latitude,longitude)

```
startWaypoint = new Bing.Maps.Directions.Waypoint(Source);
endWaypoint = new Bing.Maps.Directions.Waypoint(Destination);

waypoints = new Bing.Maps.Directions.WaypointCollection();
waypoints.Add(startWaypoint);
waypoints.Add(endWaypoint);

//Start = waypoints.IndexOf(startWaypoint);
//End = waypoints.IndexOf(endWaypoint);

directionsManager = GuideMap.DirectionsManager;
directionsManager.Waypoints = waypoints;

// Calculate route directions
Bing.Maps.Directions.RouteResponse response = await directionsManager.CalculateDirectionsAsync();

route = response.Routes[0];
// Display the route on the map
directionsManager.ShowRoutePath(response.Routes[0]);
```

Comment: I still Did not get any solution for my problem, So if anybody have any solution, are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
    directionsManager.Waypoints.Remove(startWaypoint);
```

I'm not sure haven't tested it.

To clear the route

```
    directionsManager.ClearActiveRoute();
```

Comment: **Thanks Sybren**....I had used tha code _startWaypoint = new Bing.Maps.Directions.Waypoint(Source);
 endWaypoint = new Bing.Maps.Directions.Waypoint(Destination);
waypoints = new Bing.Maps.Directions.WaypointCollection();
waypoints.Add(startWaypoint);waypoints.Add(endWaypoint); _      Now i am using Waypoint.remove(startpoint); but still i m not able to remove it.

Comment: Can you provide code part where u add the startpoint? And please edit your question and type the code there instead of in the comments.

Comment: I had edited my question with coreesponding C# code... I want to delete these watpoints at a particular event

Comment: I had already used this as well, even i used waypoint.removeat(index), and waypoint.clear(), both are not working... So can you have any other option to remove these wave points.

Comment: What happens if u clear the current route, remove a waypoint and recalculate the route? To check if a waypoint is removed from your WaypointCollection print waypoints.Count();

Comment: Sorry for too late reply, Actually i did used following sequence of code,  _waypoints.Count(); //Here is count=2 (start waypoint and end waypoint)
            waypoints.Clear(); //This use to clear waypoint

            waypoints.Count();//here count=0, still waypoint not get disappear from map, both waypoint appears_

Comment: Hi Sachin, if the waypoints are deleted from the waypointsCollection, try directionsManager.ClearActiveRoute(); and response.Routes.Clear();

Comment: thanks for your help, but response.route.clear is not valid in c#, I used ClearActiveRoute(), Still no effocts, _Even directionsManager.HideRoutePath(route); is working to hide the path, but still both waypoints"A"&"B" are visible._

Comment: You could try directionsManager.Waypoints.Clear() when this doesn't work I dont have other suggestions. Are you sure you don't add these points in another part of your code which you haven't posted here?

Comment: yes i m sure about, and           
            _waypoints.Clear();
            directionsManager.ClearActiveRoute();
            directionsManager.HideRoutePath(route);_ I used this, path hides, but waypoint still visible. anyways thanks for your precious time.

Comment: Did you also try directionsManager.Waypoints.Clear(); ? Its diffrent from waypoints.Clear()

Answer (score 0):

I got the Code for the same:-

//To clear the path or route &
//To clear or delete the Waypints of a path or route.

```
        GuideMap.DirectionsManager.HideRoutePath(GuideMap.DirectionsManager.ActiveRoute);
        GuideMap.DirectionsManager.ClearActiveRoute();
        MapLayer directionsLayer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(GuideMap, 0), 0), 0) as MapLayer;
        directionsLayer.Children.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Long time to get an answer but I'm researching the same issue on clearing a route

replace:

```
directionsManager.ShowRoutePath(response.Routes[0]);
```

with:

```
directionsManager.ActiveRoute(response.Routes[0]);
```

then the:

```
directionsManager.ClearActiveRoute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I remove all elements with:
MiMapa.Routes.Clear();
MiMapa.MapElements.Clear();
MiMapa is a MapControl in .xaml
`<my:MapControl x:Name="MiMapa"  MapServiceToken="--------"`